# QtQuick 2 - Make custom palette object and throw it as property to another custom widget (for assigning color properties)

Tags: object, properties, colors, qml, qtquick2

I trying to make custom button and few other elements styled as KDE 5 'Breeze' theme. I considered to make separated palette object (called `BreezePalette.qml` that contains a lot of readonly color properties) for all of this widgets (because I do not want them to be styled in any other way, that's thy they called Breeze). The main concept is to make palette as property of widgets and create one palette in `main.qml` where I can change property `theme` to `light` or `dark`. It looks to me rational, because I planning only include all subset of `.qml` files into project, without any other additional files to Qt itself (that making it portable and easy to deploy). Here is that I have, can someone let me know how can I forward palete as a property?

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    menuBar: MenuBar{
        Menu{
            title: "File"
        MenuItem{
            text: "Exit"
            onTriggered: Qt.quit()
        }
        }
    }
    BreezeButton{
        x: 106
        y: 82
        palette: brPalette
        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit()
        }
        caption: "Button"
    }
    BreezePalette{
        id: brPalette
        theme: "light"
    }
}
```

**BreezePalette.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.2

QtObject {
    id: palette
    property string theme: "light"
    readonly property color base: if (theme == "light"){
                                      "#eff0f1"
                                  } else if (theme == "dark"){
                                      "#31363b"
                                  }
    readonly property color focus: "#3daee9"
    readonly property color buttonText: if (theme == "light"){
                                      "#31363b"
                                  } else if (theme == "dark"){
                                      "#eff0f1"
                                  }
}
```

**BreezeButton.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
Item {
    id: root
    implicitHeight: bodyText.font.pixelSize + 32
    implicitWidth: bodyText.width + 32
    property string caption: "Button"
    property string iconSource
    property int fontSize: 18
    //I've tried to throw BreezePalette as a property to BreezeButton, but looks like my skills ended there (I have no any experience with js or qml before. I started learn it only few weeks)
    property BreezePalette palette
    signal clicked
    Rectangle {
        id: body
        border {
            width: 1
            color: "#808e8e"
        }
        anchors{
            fill: parent
        }
        gradient: Gradient {
            id: bodyGradient
            GradientStop { position: 0.4; color: "#4c4c4c" }
            GradientStop { position: 0.9; color: "#31363b" }
        }
        MouseArea{
            id: bodyMouseArea
            z: bodyText.z + 1
            anchors {
                fill: parent
            }

            hoverEnabled: true
            onEntered: {
                body.border.color = "#3daee9"

            }
            onExited: {
                body.border.color = "#7f8c8d"
            }
            onPressed: {
                body.color = "#3daee9" // this one works, but I need to switching theme as you can see n `BreezePalette.qml`
                //This one not working as expected, but seeing my properties as I need
                //body.color = palette.focus
                body.gradient = null
            }
            onReleased: {
                body.color = "#4d4d4d"
                body.gradient = bodyGradient
            }
            onClicked: {
                root.clicked()
            }
        }
        Text {
            id: bodyText
            anchors {
                verticalCenter: body.verticalCenter
                horizontalCenter: body.horizontalCenter
            }
            font.pointSize: fontSize
            color: "#fcfcfc"
            text: caption
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }
    }
}
```

Since stackexchange designed for sharing knowledge (or maybe even for ask for something you don't know well) I see it's rational to post it there because I need knowledge of experts. If you have any other point of view regarding this question I'll be glad to hear that. Appreciated any help.

Thanks
Svyatoslav

UPDATE:

Just found an answer, this code snippet working as well

```
property BreezePalette palette: BreezePalette
```

So, my second answer is - is that good to user this method? It's provide me thing I need, exactly as was expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a late answer, but there is a module to have breeze theme.

qml-module-qtquick-controls-styles-breeze